# Install elasticsearch mapper attachment plugin

Tags: elasticsearch

If I want to install elasticsearch-mapper-attachment plugin `$ES_HOME$\elasticsearch-1.0.0\bin\plugin.bat -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/2.0.0.RC1` should I install Apache Tika before or comes Tika with the ElasticSearch installation?

Comment: All req dependencies *should* be packaged in the plugin. Be sure to restart your es instance and check the logs to verify the plugin was installed correctly.

Comment: I can't found any log which contains an entry about the installation of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin should include Tika already. All you need to do is to upload a document's base64 encoded attachment using the curl API.